# DynamoDB Cannot insert anything but Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am experimenting with DynamoDB to insert some data in a table `test-table`.
With postman and Lambda, I am trying to insert some values.

Currently, my table has a `Key` called `node`, and if I try to insert a new record doing the following in the body works:

```
 {
    "TableName": "test-table",
        "Key": {"note":"test node"}
}
```

However, I want to add some new data to my record, for example:

```
 {
    "TableName": "test-table",
        "Key": {"note":"test node"},
        "Title": "This is a test"
}
```

But doing this does not save the second property `Title`, only the key get saved.
What am I missing here?

Here is my Lambda code that receives data with API Gateway:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    let body;
    let statusCode = '200';
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    try {
        switch (event.httpMethod) {
            case 'DELETE':
                body = await dynamo.delete(JSON.parse(event.body)).promise();
                break;
            case 'GET':
                body = await dynamo.scan({ TableName: event.queryStringParameters.TableName }).promise();
                break;
            case 'POST':
                body = await dynamo.put(JSON.parse(event.body)).promise();
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                body = await dynamo.update(JSON.parse(event.body)).promise();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error(`Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        statusCode = '400';
        body = err.message;
    } finally {
        body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }

    return {
        statusCode,
        body,
        headers,
    };
};
```

Comment: It did not seems a valid request. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#API_PutItem_Examples

Comment: Try `{ "TableName": "test-table", "Item": { "note": { "S": "test node"}, "title": { "S": "fred" }}}`

Comment: @jarmod, unluckily it doesn't work as well, it only saves  the key, nothing else.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that both your original and my variant would store the key attribute successfully, because your key is under "Key" and mine is under "Item". So, you haven't shared some key piece of information. You mentioned Postman and Lambda. How are they connected? Are you using API Gateway in front of Lambda and having Postman make API requests against API Gateway? If so, then you should show your Lambda code.

Comment: @jarmod, I noticed it and changed from "Item" to "Key". Anyway, I've updated the question with the Lambda code!

Comment: With the document client, you would put `{ "TableName": "test-table", "Item": { "note": "test node", "title": "fred" }}`

Comment: Thanks, but unluckily i'm getting this error: `"The provided key element does not match the schema"`. Of course, I changed from `Item` to `Key`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209857/discussion-between-jarmod-and-sanna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the DynamoDB Document Client, your code should ultimately look like this:

```
const params = { "TableName": "test-table", "Item": { "note": "test", "title": "fred" }};
const rc = await dynamo.put(params).promise();
```

Note specifically that the top-level attributes in the `params` that you pass to the `put()` method are `TableName` and `Item`, rather than `TableName` and `Key`. So, be sure that your parsed HTTP body matches that.

Also, because your client (the web page) is actually supplying the table name to your Lambda function, be sure to secure this application from the [Confused Deputy Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem) where someone hacks the HTTP body to reference a different table, such as `employees` or `students`.